# Searching for single value against multiple columns

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to send a `searchString` from user and want to search it against mutiple columns of a `Order` table of my database. E.g if user send s string "abc" then i have to search in order table if `customerEmail` field contain "abc" or "OrderId" field contain "abc" or `"PostelCode"` field contains "abc"
then all these accumulative records will be returned.

```
 public ActionResult SearchOrders(string searchString)
    {
        var searchedOrders = dbContextObject.Orders.Where( //here comes the actual comparison)
        if (searchedOrders.Count > 0)
        {
            return View("_searchedOrders", searchedOrders); ;
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("No Record found");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
public ActionResult SearchOrders(string searchString)
{
    var q = searchString.Trim().ToLower();

    var searchedOrders = dbContextObject.Orders.Where( t =>
                           t.CustomerEmail.ToLower().Contains(q) ||
                           t.OrderId.ToLower().Contains(q) ||
                           t.PostelCode.ToLower().Contains(q));
    if (searchedOrders.Count > 0)
    {
        return View("_searchedOrders", searchedOrders);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json("No Record found");
    }
}
```